# What will happen if I change the category code of digits to 11? (i.e. \makedigitsletter)

Tags: catcodes

In [this post](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.text.tex/9NmusZ8C9Rg), 
@Heiko Oberdiek said

> BUT each number TeX expects have to be catcode 12 (the problems)! Eg. `\hspace{1em}`

What does he meant by "each number"? In addition to counters/dimensions/glues, which of the following will break?

```
\def\cs#1{}
\box 255
\numexpr 1+1 \relax
\ifcase 1 ... \fi
\char"26
$1+1$
```

(please feel free to expand the list)

Comment: There is no problem when you want to print a number. The issue is when the digits are part of syntax

Comment: @egreg I quite upset. Roman numeral makes my code ugly since the lengths of control sequences vary.

Comment: @Symbol1 You could use descriptive names, rather than roman numerals, or letters, like “wipet style” `\def\foo{} \def\fooA{} \def\fooB{} \def\fooC{} \def\fooL{} \def\fooX{}`, etc.

Answer (score 3):

It can be immediately see from this syntax scheme borrowed from the TeXbook, page 269, that essentially ***all*** syntactic constructs requiring a number will break if digits have category code 11 and not 12.

> ⟨number⟩ → ⟨optional signs⟩⟨unsigned number⟩
>   ⟨optional signs⟩ → ⟨optional spaces⟩
>      | ⟨optional signs⟩⟨plus or minus⟩⟨optional spaces⟩
>   ⟨unsigned number⟩ → ⟨normal integer⟩ | ⟨coerced integer⟩
>   ⟨normal integer⟩ → ⟨internal integer⟩
>      | ⟨integer constant⟩⟨one optional space⟩
>      | `'`<sub>12</sub>⟨octal constant⟩⟨one optional space⟩
>      | `"`<sub>12</sub>⟨hexadecimal constant⟩⟨one optional space⟩
>      | `` ` ``<sub>12</sub>⟨character token⟩⟨one optional space⟩
>   ⟨integer constant⟩ → ⟨digit⟩ | ⟨digit⟩⟨integer constant⟩
>   ⟨octal constant⟩ → ⟨octal digit⟩ | ⟨octal digit⟩⟨octal constant⟩
>   ⟨hexadecimal constant⟩ → ⟨hex digit⟩ | ⟨hex digit⟩⟨hexadecimal constant⟩
>   ⟨octal digit⟩ → `0`<sub>12</sub> | `1`<sub>12</sub> | `2`<sub>12</sub> | `3`<sub>12</sub> |
>       `4`<sub>12</sub> | `5`<sub>12</sub> | `6`<sub>12</sub> | `7`<sub>12</sub>
>   ⟨digit⟩ → ⟨octal digit⟩ | `8`<sub>12</sub> | `9`<sub>12</sub>
>   ⟨hex digit⟩ → ⟨digit⟩ | `A`<sub>11</sub> | `B`<sub>11</sub> | `C`<sub>11</sub> |
>       `D`<sub>11</sub> | `E`<sub>11</sub> | `F`<sub>11</sub>
>      | `A`<sub>12</sub> | `B`<sub>12</sub> | `C`<sub>12</sub> |
>       `D`<sub>12</sub> | `E`<sub>12</sub> | `F`<sub>12</sub>
>   ⟨one optional space⟩ → ⟨space token⟩ | ⟨empty⟩
>   ⟨coerced integer⟩ → ⟨internal dimen⟩ | ⟨internal glue⟩

Also definitions like `\def\cs#1{...}` would break, because the syntax prescribes that the digit following `#` has category code 12, if we want a parameter.

You'd have no problem when *printing* numbers, but simple things such as `\\[1ex]` would break horribly.

You might always `\detokenize` your syntactic numbers, because TeX will perform expansion when in need of a ⟨number⟩:

```
\hspace{\detokenize{1}em}
```

would work in the document. Is this worth the pain?